# No Catalyst Control Center

Tags: ati, catalyst

I have installed the AMD driver in 12.04 using the Additional Drivers function. It works fine, fglrxinfo returns correct information, but it seems that there is no Catalyst Control Center, I tried installing fglrx-amdcccle, but still it does not appear when I search installed programs.

Answer (score 4):

Just run `amdcccle` from terminal, you can also make a shortcut, to run as root use `sudo amdcccle`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y fglrx-updates

$ gksu amdcccle
```

This line will open the AMD Catalyst as Administrator (you will be prompted for superuser password to use it (your root password)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Unity panel or the default Gnome?
Install Gnome Shell and then do a search for "AMD".
If this still dosen't work, try installign it from Synaptic Package Manager.

Comment: I'm using XFCE actually, I can run the file manually, but not from terminal or otherwise, only if I navigate to that folder.